# Chromium Maximizes when I change Workspaces

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-2d, chromium

Every time I switch from one workspace to another and then back, Chromium somehow manages to automatically maximize itself. After a while, it crashes Unity somehow. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. The problem goes away and then returns... and then goes away... and then returns... repeatedly as well.

Comment: How are you switching workspaces?  ctrl-alt-left_arrow/right_arrow, shift-ctrl-alt-left_arrow/right_arrow, workspace switcher, or what?  I'm unable to replicate your problem so far with the method's I've tried...

Comment: I have tried it on both unity and LXDE, and nothing happens.  The windows stays the same in all workspaces. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, adempewolff! I am using ctrl-alt-left/right/up/down arrows.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. Yes. When I start Chromium, it starts maximized. I then resize the window to the way I like it. If I then use ctrl-alt-rightarrow to move to Workspace 2, and ctrl-alt-leftarrow to move back to Workspace 1, the Chromium window will automatically maximize itself.

Comment: It happens to me as well; I switch workspaces by having (eg) Skype in a different workspace and clicking on skype in the task bar.  I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Eclipse appears to have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I confirm this behaviour with Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity 2D.

Some relevant bug reports with more info:

- [Ubuntu Bug #1040174: Windows maximised when switching workspaces](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1040174)
- [Ubuntu unity-2d Bug #963416: windows maximized after switching workspaces](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/963416)
- [Ayatana Design Bug #946649: Unity destroys window layout (maximize) on switching workspaces](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/946649)
- [Ayatana Design Bug #797808: Window auto-maximise functionality should be disabled on monitors with a resolution above 1024 x 600](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/797808)

Try running this command from the terminal for a workaround:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/metacity/general/auto_maximize_windows false
```

This is very annoying. If I have several Firefox windows open on one workspace and switch workspaces and switch back again, then suddenly I have **all** of those windows maximized one behind another, I have to unmaximize them one by one, reposition every one of them once again and remember to never switch workspace or otherwise have the layout ruined once more. It makes the whole idea of having workspaces pretty much useless if I have to clean a mess every time I switch them.